# Unity 2D array tile map

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, 2d

I am new to Unity as well as C#. Yet, I am trying to make a simple 2D platform game where I made a prefab of an object called Block. What I want to be able to do is to create an array tile map with 0s and 1s where the 1s are blocks and 0s are nothing. Also, I don't want the tile map to be random. I want the blocks to be instantiated from another object called GameController. A perfect example of what I would like to achieve is something like this.

[image]

But I don't really know how to do this with an array. I want to keep things simple since I am trying to learn how unity and c# work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So you can use some assets from the asset store( for example: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/list/2965-procedural-generation) This is a pretty hard challange. I would recomand this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k1pWpYEt2UE , but the closest one to what you want to achieve is this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gIUVRYViG_g
Hope it helped.

Comment: This videos do certainly help, but I think I forgot to mention that I do not want the tile map to be random, I want to be able to specify were the tiles will be through the array by using 0s and 1s, 1s for the blocks, and 0s for nothing.

Comment: I think this is something similar for your goal: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=93o_Ad5C5Ds The way he arranged the pieces is the as you want to put your titles, the only difference is that his array goes 10101010 and than next row

Answer (score 0):

You can make a 2 dimensional array, e.g. int[40, 100] and loop through it twice, and if the number in the array is one, multiply your position in the array by the length or width of your block respectively. For example:

```
int[,] positions = new int[40,100];

for (int i = 0; i < 41; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
        if (positions[i,j] = 1) {
            GameObject temp = Instantiate(block, new Vector3(j * blockWidth, i * blockHeight, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        }
    }
}
```

It would take a long while to set all of the coordinates for an array this large, but you could loop through with parameters, or just do it the hard way if it is smaller. Otherwise, I would just try doing it without a script.

Comment: That is exactly what I want to do, thanks. But how do I exactly assign the array to 0s and 1s? I'm sorry if my question seems stupid.

Comment: @nico.user, One way of doing it might be to make a grid, and if you click on a space in the grid, add a block there. Then, save the grid after run time. This is not easy, but it is easier than putting all the ones and zeroes in manually. I can't think of any better ways